# Upper bounding Lerch zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\Phi\left(z,s,a\right) $ be a [Lerch Trascendent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function). 
 $$\Phi\left(z,s,a\right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}e^{-at}}{1-ze^{-t}}dt.$$

Can we upper bound the above in terms of its parameters (for positive reals $z, a$ and real $s$)?

Pls let me know if there is any doubt regarding the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sum representation of the same function is a simple expression in terms of the parameters that give a bound (more, the exact value). It won't get simpler as a closed expression. I'm pretty sure that for s=1, the function always explodes past z=1.